# iOS UITableViewCell adding label and image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add text label or UIImage (does not matter) in UITableViewCell.
But it did not appear. I am using few views in this cell. You can see it in the code below:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"timelineCell";
        KMWTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell)
        {
            cell = [cell initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 10, 293, 200)];

            UIView *cellContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 10, 293, 200)];
            cellContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            cellContentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
            cellContentView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
            cellContentView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
            cellContentView.layer.shadowOpacity = .25;
            cellContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBack"]];


            UIView *selectedContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 10, 293, 200)];
            selectedContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            selectedContentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
            selectedContentView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
            selectedContentView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
            selectedContentView.layer.shadowOpacity = .25;
            selectedContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackActive"]];


            UIView *visibleContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 10, 293, 200)];
            visibleContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            visibleContentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
            visibleContentView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
            visibleContentView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
            visibleContentView.layer.shadowOpacity = .25;
            visibleContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//Image adding here:
 [ UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"active.png"]];
        [visibleContentView addSubview:image];

            [cellContentView addSubview:visibleContentView];
            [selectedContentView addSubview:visibleContentView];

            [cell setBackgroundView:cellContentView];
            [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedContentView];

        }

        return cell;
    }
```

As you can see I am using backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView and also view with other info with clearColor. So why other elements do not display in visibleView?

**UPDATE:**

I am using subclass because I need to change frame size of cell.

Comment: If you are using a `UITableViewCell` subclass why are you still doing all this?

Comment: This is not about the problem, but why are you adding `visibleContentView` into two views `cellContentView` and `selectedContentView`. Why don't you simply add it to `selectedContentView`.

Comment: Hm I was thinking that if I add `visibleContentView` only to `cellContentView` it will be hidden by `selectedContentView` when user will tap on cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are adding `visibleContentView` into `selectedContentView` right after you add it to `cellContentView`. That removes it from `cellContentView` because a view can only have one superview at a time. So the `visibleContentView` is actually in the `selectedContentView`. If `KMWTableViewCell` works properly, you should see the missing components when the cell is selected.

Comment: You are right! But I need `visibleContentView` not to disappear while user tap on cell. So I need to create two different views with the same content, one for `cellContent` view and second for `selectedContentView`?

Comment: Yep, that should work. But I didn't think it would disappear. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing "KMWtableViewCell" in line

```
KMWTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I think KMWTableViewCell might be creating a problem.

Comment: I could not, just because I need to change cell frame size and it only possible with creating subclass

Answer (score 0):

I can't really know if it's the right answer, since I'm away from my mac, but I think you should replace

```
KMWTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with

```
KMWTableViewCell *cell = (KMWTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

hope it helped!

Comment: Tnx for answer but the reason was that I tried to add subview in two views